# How to end piped http request?

Tags: javascript, node.js

[According to doc's](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback), the `http.request()` method should be "ended" after you are done:

```
req.end();
```

How do you go about doing this if you are piping to the request? For example:

```
fs.createReadStream(fileInput).pipe(https.request(options, function(res){
    console.log(res);
}));
```

Where do you call `.end()`?

Answer (score 0):

since the `request` object is what has the `end` method, i'd expect this to work:

```
fs.createReadStream(fileInput).pipe(https.request(options, function(res){
    console.log(res);
}).end());
```

Comment: I considered that but I'm wondering if that would end the request too early in some cases since I assume request is async.... I'm not sure how to tell...